# How do I properly chain Promises when both creating a new user and hashing their password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to make a POST request that creates a new account. It first checks if there is already an account using that email. If there isn't, it then creates a new account and stores it in a user collection. It also does two things, it hashes the person's password and generates a token for that user when the account is created. Here is my code for my first attempt:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const authentication = require('../controllers/authentication');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportService =require('../services/passport');
const config = require('../config/config');
const User = require('../model/user');
const router = express.Router();
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

    router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

        // I guess I will have to use this, and set this to true or false within findOne

        let doesExist_ = undefined;

        function generateUserToken(user){

            return jwt.encode({sub: user._id, iat: timeStamp}, config.secretKey);

        }

        if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
            return res.status(442).send({error: 'Make sure that you entered your email and password'});
        }

        /// this doesn't return a boolean

        User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

            .then((err, user) => {
                if (user !== null || user !== undefined){
                    doesExist_ = true;
                    console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);
                }
                else {
                    doesExist_ = false;
                    console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);
                }
            })
            .then(() => {

                console.log('in second Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);


                if (!doesExist_){

                    let password = req.body.password;

                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
                        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash){
                            if (err) throw err;
                            password = hash;
                        })
                    }).then(() => {

                        User.create({
                            username: req.body.username,
                            password: password,
                            name: req.body.name,
                            email: req.body.email,
                            profilePic: req.body.profilePic,
                            ///  userId: userid
                        }).then((user) => {

                            res.json({token: generateUserToken(user)});

                        })

                    });

                }

                else {

                    return res.status(422).send({error: "Email is already in use"});
                }

            })

            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });


    });
```

However, it isn't working, every time I try to create a new User, it fails to do so. Postman takes three minutes to process the request and when I check Robomongo afterwards, the user I just created is not in the collection.

I also wrote a second version of this making use of promises. I thought maybe the problem was that I needed to make my code wait for bcrypt to hash the password, then I could create and save the entry to the database:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const authentication = require('../controllers/authentication');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportService =require('../services/passport');
const config = require('../config/config');
const User = require('../model/user');
const router = express.Router();
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

    // I guess I will have to use this, and set this to true or false within findOne

    let doesExist_ = undefined;

    function generateUserToken(user){

        return jwt.encode({sub: user._id, iat: timeStamp}, config.secretKey);

    }

    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(442).send({error: 'Make sure that you entered your email and password'});
    }

    /// this doesn't return a boolean

    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

        .then((user) => {
        /// this should be null if it doesn't exist
            if (user !== null){
                doesExist_ = true;
                console.log('in first Then, user is...' + user);
                console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is...' + doesExist_);
            }
            else {
                doesExist_ = false;
                console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {

            console.log('in second Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);


            if (!doesExist_){

                let password = req.body.password;

                let hashedPassword;

                bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
                    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash){
                        if (err) throw err;
                        hashedPassword = hash;
                        console.log('hashedPassword is now...' + hashedPassword + ' and the hash is...' + hash);
                    })
                });

                let hashPromise = () => {

                    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

                        if (hashedPassword !== undefined && hashedPassword !== null){
                            console.log('Within hashPromise, hashedPassword is...' + hashedPassword);
                            resolve();
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Within hashPromise, hashedPassword is...' + hashedPassword);
                            reject('hashedPassword is still undefined');
                        }
                    });
                };


                hashPromise().then(() => {

                    User.create({
                        username: req.body.username,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        name: req.body.name,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        profilePic: req.body.profilePic,
                        ///  userId: userid
                    }).then((user) => {

                        res.json({token: generateUserToken(user)});

                    })

                });

            }

            else {

                return res.status(422).send({error: "Email is already in use"});
            }

        })

        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

However, I am still running into the same problems with this version. It is running for a long ass time in Postman, and when the server times out, I still don't have the entry added to the collection. Am I chaining the promises correctly in this approach?

When I run this version I get this console log:

```
    in first Then, doesExist_ is false
    in second Then, doesExist_ is false
    Within hashPromise, hashedPassword is...undefined
    (node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): hashedPassword is still
     undefined
    hashedPassword is now...$2a$10$2VQ6AlaEgnrCvt8udshnZe/auswqawe8eZ1f5IXESmKmQVEI7nYNa and the hash is...$2a$10$2VQ6Al
    aEgnrCvt8udshnZe/auswqawe8eZ1f5IXESmKmQVEI7nYNa
```

Before Bcrypt finishes hashing the password,  I get the console.log from my Promise. Is the console.log an indicator that the Promise is not working? The Promise is supposed to be resolved once the variable hashedPassword is no longer undefined after bcrypt finishes hashing it. But it doesn't appear to be running as I intended.

Any tips as to how I can fix either versions? Am I doing too much in a single request given that I am also generating a token as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard bcrypt library does not return a promise - if you want to work with promises, you could use [bcrypt-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-promise).

If you want to use the standard bcrypt lib, you'll have to work in the callback:

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then((user) => {   
        if (user !== null){
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                    // this is the function bcrypt calls when it's done
                    if (err) throw err;

                    User.create({
                        username: req.body.username,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        name: req.body.name,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        profilePic: req.body.profilePic,
                        ///  userId: userid
                    }).then((user) => {
                        res.json({token: generateUserToken(user)});
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

(reduced example to show nesting - you'll still need to handle your errors and stuff)

alternatively - because callbacks get nested deep really quickly, you can of course create an extra function and give that to bcrypt as a callback:

```
var afterHash = function(err, hash){
    if (err) throw err;

    User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hashedPassword,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        profilePic: req.body.profilePic,
        ///  userId: userid
    }).then((user) => {
        res.json({token: generateUserToken(user)});
    });
};

User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then((user) => {   
        if (user !== null){
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, afterHash);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning how to use mongoose and I did not get to learning about hashes yet but I glimpsed at the docs and I think you are not using the methods correctly ...

first of all [mongo docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) say that findone (queries) don't return a promise but have a [`then()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-then) function

I would try something like :

---

```
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).exec()

    .then((user) => {
    /// this should be null if it doesn't exist
        if (user !== null){
            doesExist_ = true;
            console.log('in first Then, user is...' + user);
            console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is...' + doesExist_);
        }
        else {
            doesExist_ = false;
            console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);
        }
    })
```

---

or:

---

```
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

    .then((user) => {
        doesExist_ = true;
        console.log(user);
        console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is...' + doesExist_);
    },(err) => 
    {
        doesExist_ = false;
        console.log(err);
        console.log('in first Then, doesExist_ is ' + doesExist_);
    }
)
```

---

second of all bcrypt's [`genSalt()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs#gensaltrounds-seed_length-callback) and [`hash()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs#hashs-salt-callback-progresscallback) return a promise If the callbacks are omitted ...

Hope I was of help ...